# true or false based on one or more highlighted cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which looks like [image: this].

I want an output like [image: this].

If any one of the cells in three columns is highlighted, then the output for that row should be `1` else `0`. The output column is named `count` in linked output image.

For example: cells `B2` and `C2` are highlighted in the first row, so the output cell `D2` should be `1`. `A4`, `B4`, and `C4` don't have any highlighted cells, so the output D4 should be `0`.

Would someone please help me with a function for this?

Comment: I don't have Excel available to test, but one possible workaround is creating three new columns with values 1 or 0 that will conditionally format (with highlighting) the original three columns. It will be easier to get the desired value in `count` with these three new binary columns. If this isn't feasible, you may need to do something with macros as described here: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010780_Colors_in_an_IF_Function.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this [user-defined-function](/questions/tagged/user-defined-function),

```
Option Explicit

Function IsHighlighted(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        IsHighlighted = IsHighlighted Or CBool(r.Interior.Pattern <> xlNone)
    Next r
    IsHighlighted = Abs(IsHighlighted)
End Function
```